# Given a SqlError object how to determine whether it denotes a Warning or a Caution?

Tags: .net, sql-server

So, I have a `SqlError` .NET object. How do I know whether it denotes a Warning or a Caution?

I can inspect the `SqlError.Message` and see whether it starts with **Warning:** or **Caution:**. But I do not like it.

I feel `SqlError.Number` should have some bits allocated for the severity, but I just cannot find it in the documentation.

Any ideas?

Example of warning message - **Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.**

Example of a caution message - **Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.**

Comment: Is this in dotnet code? I am missing something here.

Comment: Sorry, added that it is .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlException` and a `SqlError` both have a `.Class`, which is the severity level as defined by [`RAISERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql). This defines errors vs warnings, as summarised here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.class(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question - how to tell apart Warnings from Cautions. So far both Warnings and Cautions had `Class == 0`

Comment: @mark then they are informational, and there is nothing more you know about them

Comment: @mark, both these messages are warnings in SQL Server with severity 10. The word "caution" is just part of the message text as there is no concept of a caution message in SQL Server .NET returns 0 as the Class for all errors with severity < 11. A SqlException will be raised by default for severity > 10 and the Class will reflect the error severity returned by SQL Server.